# Am I doing this right? Trying to manipulate the master page style for one particular page that inherits it

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

My master page has the menu. By clicking on the "home" link takes me to home.aspx page. I want the home button to be in a different css while I'm on that page. I came across multiple posts but this one from Jeremy caught my eye and looked simple enough.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10871099/1851048 . 


I tried to implement the same in my website but its not working. I get this: "'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' is a type not a namespace"

This is the .cs code in my home.aspx.cs:

```
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


  public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page

 {
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   }

  }

 public class HtmlGenericControl : HtmlContainerControl
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
       HtmlGenericControls mycontrol = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Page.Master.FindControl("yourcontrolname") as HtmlGenericControl;

          mycontrol.Attributes.Add("class", "cssToApply");
      }
 }
```

I did some research here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx

But I got different errors each time. I managed to get rid of all of them but then the code wouldn't work.

This is my first website so I currently have a lot to learn. Appreciate your help.

Edit:

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page

 {
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           var mycontrol = this.Page.Master.FindControl("HyperLink1") as HtmlGenericControl;

           mycontrol.Attributes.Add("class", "cssToApply");

       }

 }
```

CSS:

```
  #menu ul
 {
padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
  }

   #menu li
   {    
margin: auto;
display:inline;
   }

 #menu a 
  {
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: white;
margin: 6px;
float: left;
width: 150px;
height: 27px;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1.5em;
   }

 #menu a:hover
 {
   background-color: white;
   color: #bee2f1;
 }

 .cssToApply
 {
   background-color: white;
   color: #bee2f1;
  }
```

MasterPage.master:

```
                     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="home.aspx">Home</asp:HyperLink></li>
```

Comment: check this may be help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023188/create-handler-that-manipulates-head-tag/14023310#14023310

Answer (score 0):

Here your problem is you don't need to create separate class for `HtmlGenericControl` and your namespace is also wrong (it should be `HtmlControls`).

Try with below code (replace your code with below).

```
using System;    
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;


  public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          var mycontrol = this.Page.Master.FindControl("yourcontrolname") as HtmlGenericControl;

          mycontrol.Attributes.Add("class", "cssToApply");

       }
   }
```

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: I tried it and I got this error: Object reference not set to an instance of the object. This control I am trying to change the color of, is the asp:Hyperlink.

Comment: can you put that whole error on your post ? and your final code also.

Comment: To be more clear, I have done the following changes to the code as for my requirements: the control ID is "HyperLink1" and I have created a new class in my stylesheet "cssToApply" which should provide the style to my hyperlink control.

Comment: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." is the error and it saying that mycontrol.Attributes.Add("class", "cssToApply"); is the problem.

Comment: can you put your final code on your original post not as a comment (very difficult to see when it's on comment section).Need to put your Html and also CSS.

Comment: Done the editing. Notice the #menu a:hover style? I want the same style to be preserved when I navigate to the home page.